# VB.NET DataSet "Value is already present" handling

Tags: vb.net, dataset, constraints

I am using VB.NET and Visual Studio 2017. I have a DataSet, that has two columns: ID and ToolDiameter. Both of the columns have to be unique and the "Unique" property is set as "True".

The data is entered to the DataSet manually. When a duplicate ToolDiameter is entered, I get the error System.Data.ConstraintException: 'Column 'ToolDiameter' is constrained to be unique.  Value '57' is already present.'

I would like it to show a MessageBox to the user, informing that the tool is already present, but I have now idea where exactly to add the code, since I am using BindingNavigator and DataGridView.

Best Regards,
SilverR

Comment: If you're using a `DataGridView` and entering the data via that, I think that the error dialogue that displays actually tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Yep, just tested and confirmed that the dialogue displayed tells you what to do. If you are presented with information by the IDE, you ought to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad, forgot to mention that I tried to enter new data using textbox (DataSet Details). That's why I didn't see the error dialogue. I solved that error with DataGridView like this:

```
Private Sub PunchToolsRODataGridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles PunchToolsRODataGridView1.DataError
    MessageBox.Show("Entry error!", "Error")
    If (e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Value already exists.", "Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

But The problem with using TextBox still persists.